# What is Windows Enhanced Storage?

Tags: windows-7, dll, shell-extensions, removable-media

I got an strange icon overlay on my USB stick drive:

[image: The strange icon]

[In my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/397084/what-is-the-circle-with-a-vertical-line-icon-appearing-on-removable-disk-icons) I could identify it's `EhStorShell.dll` drawing that overlay there (Thanks!). The dll has the description `Windows Enhanced Storage Shell Extension DLL`.

So what is it? and how to turn this enhanced storing thing off (I don't mind) to get the normal non-overlayed icon?

Comment: have you tried doing a full reformat of the USB drive?

Comment: To be honest, I think you might do better to just buy another USB stick instead of trying to get around this.. I feel that this would be very difficult to get around as it's built into Windows since Vista. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430343(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft:

> An Enhanced Storage device can be an external USB hard drive or a USB flash drive. When you purchase a USB hard drive or flash drive, the packaging might indicate that it's an Enhanced Storage device.

Microsoft have created a technology that helps protect user data on portable storage devices that allows for additional security.

In their own words:

> Enhanced Storage devices have built-in safety features that let you control who can access the data on the device by using a password or a certificate (if the device is being used in a workplace). Once someone has access to the device, they have access to the data because the data on the device is not encrypted.

However, in regards to encryption, Microsoft states:

> Some device manufacturers might offer encryption on Enhanced Storage devices. Check the device packaging or documentation to see if the device includes encryption.

Source (now archived): [What is Enhanced Storage?](https://web.archive.org/web/20120110124118/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/What-is-Enhanced-Storage)

(I will investigate how to turn Enhanced Storage off, but I have a feeling you won't be able to because it is implemented on the external device itself... I will report back with a more definitive answer though.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you *really* want is "to get the non-overlayed icon", rather than to turn off enhanced storage. Try (exporting and then) deleting the registry key at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\EnhancedStorageShell
```

Any **new** Windows Explorer windows from then on will not load the overlay. (Existing Explorer windows will have already loaded it and will continue to show it.)